# Extending System.Convert

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, types, type-conversion

System.Convert has a really useful utility for converting datatypes from one type to another.  In my project, I have many custom types.  I want to convert command line arguments to these custom types (some of which are quite complex).  It would be nice if these existed within System.Convert  so I could just do something like this:

```
Convert.ToMyCustomType(args[1])
```

I'd like for this to show up in the Visual C# IDE as I type.  I know that I could simply create a routine to convert types but I would like the type conversions to be handled in the same manner as what's already built into the framework.  Has anyone had success doing this in the past?

Comment: What would such a thing give you over extension methods?

Comment: @Oded: Convert is a static class.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Of course it is... wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you can't add them to the [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class - I would suggest adding conversion methods to your actual types, such as:

```
MyCustomType.FromInt32(...)
```

and instance methods going the other way:

```
int x = myCustomType.ToInt32();
```

(Static factory methods are often better than adding lots of overloaded constructors, IMO. They allows various alternatives - including returning a null value where appropriate, or caching - and can make the calling code clearer.)

I would also strongly recommend that you *don't* go overboard on the number of conversions you supply. Not many custom types really have a single natural conversion from all kinds of primitive types.

Comment: This would probably be the next best thing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, System.Convert is not a namespace; it is a static class (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) for more information).  You can write your own Convert class!

```
static class Convert
{
    static MyCustomType ToMyCustomType(string value)
    {
         //logic here...
    }
}
```

If you want to use this class in the same file where you're using System.Convert, you might want to give it another name, to reduce ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `System.Convert` is a static class and you cannot extend static classes. You can only derive static classes from `object`.

---

A possible way to go, is to provide conversion operators (either implicit or explicit)

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static explicit operator MyClass(SomeOtherType other)
    {
        return new MyClass { /* TODO: provide a conversion here*/ };
    }

    public static explicit operator SomeOtherType(MyClass x)
    {
        return new SomeOtherType {  /* TODO: provide a conversion here*/ };
    }
}
```

With this declaration you can do this

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
SomeOtherType other = (SomeOtherType)myClass;
```

or this

```
SomeOtherType other = new SomeOtherType();
MyClass myClass = (MyClass)other;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert` is a static class, which you can't extend.

However, you can use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.changetype.aspx) for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type - or types - you will be converting from you *can* use extension methods (but not of `System.Convert`, as mentioned elsewhere).

For example, converting to a hexadecimal string from an array of byte (such as when you want a nicely formatted hex string from a hash), you can do this:

```
''' <summary>Converts a byte array to a hexadecimal string.</summary>
''' <param name="Item">Required. The array of byte to convert.</param>
''' <returns>A hexadecimal string if converted successfully, error otherwise.</returns>
<Extension()>
Public Function [ToHexString](
    ByVal Item As Byte()) As String

    Dim Result As String = ""
    If Item IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each b As Byte In Item
            Result += b.ToString("X2")
        Next b
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim myHexString As String = myByteArray.ToHexString()
```

Result:

```
FEE53B1AB64BD74AF8A95A9D4078141F196BA7A3
```

You can add an optional parameter to select upper- or lower-casing of the result if you want to get fancy.

And you can overload the methods according to the type you are converting, so you could have one for converting from, say, `Long` (though that's already doable with standard `String` functions).